# Does scheduling recycling app pool in IIS7 help the server conserve memory better?

Tags: application-pools, memory-usage, memory-leak, low-memory

I have a VPS (IIS7 with Win 2008)

It's got: 40 websites and a SQL Server 2008 powering them with only 2 Gigs of RAM.

**None** of the sites are mission critical, they are all just demos.
I often have ram issues on the server because each site has does caching and generally uses a lot of memory.

**Would it make sense to set the application pools to recycle every 3 hours?**

I'm sure this would free up any memory leaks or processes left "hanging"

Are there any other tips on this?

Thank you very much!, Aron

Answer (score 1):

App pool recycling can help but it's really only a sticking plaster in this case, and should not be relied on as your primary strategy.  i'll bet that each one of those sites has it's own separate app pool, and that if you reconfigured them to share the same pool as much as is possible you will see better performance gains that don't require nursemaiding.